# Toggle visibility with click on original element or another element

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a function that makes an element visible when called:

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('first');">Button</a>
<a class="url" id="first" href="#">First</a>
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('second');">Button2</a>
<a class="url" id="second" href="#">Second</a>
```

And that works, but what I want is for an element to toggle off if I use the function for a different id.  So if I first toggle on #first but then toggle on #second I want #first to toggle off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var lastId = null;
function toggle_visibility(id) {
      if (lastId && id != lastId) {
          var lastEl = document.getElementById(lastId);
          lastEl.style.display = 'none';
      }
      lastId = id;
      var e = document.getElementById(id);
      if(e.style.display == 'block')
         e.style.display = 'none';
      else
         e.style.display = 'block';
      }
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('first');">Button</a>
<a class="url" style='display:block' id="first" href="#">First</a>
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('second');">Button2</a>
<a class="url" style='display:block' id="second" href="#">Second</a>
```

Comment: Worked great!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution.

```js
     function toggle_visibility(id) {
             if (id=='first'){
              var e = document.getElementById(id);
              var f = document.getElementById('second');
               }
       else {var e = document.getElementById(id);
              var f = document.getElementById('first');}
              if(e.style.display == 'block'){
                 e.style.display = 'none';
                 f.style.display= 'block';}
       
              else
                { e.style.display = 'block';
                 f.style.display = 'none';}
              }
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('first');">Button</a>
    <a class="url" id="first" href="#">First</a>
    <a class="button" href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('second');">Button2</a>
    <a class="url" id="second" href="#">Second</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
toggle_visibility = function(id) {
    var all_urls = document.getElementsByClassName('url');
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    for(var i=0;i<all_urls.length;i++){
      if(all_urls[i].id !== id)
        all_urls[i].style.display= 'none';
    }
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
    else
      e.style.display = 'block';
 }
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('first');">Button</a>
<a class="url" id="first" href="#">First</a>
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('second');">Button2</a>
<a class="url" id="second" href="#">Second</a>
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks